# Detect flash objects in html code

Tags: javascript, html, object-tag

I need to detect whether a page contains flash objects ,*I do not mean browser flash support*.
Have you sorted out something similar?

Comment: Maybe you can search inside your page for `OBJECT` tag.

Comment: correct! I search for swf,object,embed,iframe.but what is the guarantee that its flash they might also represent other things like iframe might display map.They might be commented as well.I hope there is a js way of doing this thing like for scripts we have document.scripts.

Answer (score 1):

A shorter version of [giannis christofakis' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17001435/999) for [modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3) (should work in IE9+):

```
function containsSWFObjects() {
    var s, 
        selectors = [
            'object param[name="movie"][value*=".swf"]',
            'object param[name="src"][value*=".swf"]',
            'embed[src*=".swf"]',
            'object[data*=".swf"]'
        ];

    while (s = selectors.pop()) {
        if (document.querySelectorAll(s).length) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

You can use jQuery instead of document.querySelectorAll which might be slightly slower, but will probably work with every browser.

Answer (score 0):

My approach is to distinguish flash objects from others *such as pictures and videos* by their file extension. It's the only thing that it cannot be omitted. You can spot some cases below.

```
function getFileExtension(filename) {
    //Since you only looking for swf.
    return filename.substr(filename.length - 3).toUpperCase(); 
    //return filename.split('.').pop().toUpperCase();
}

function isSwfFile(filename) {
    if ( getFileExtension(filename) == "SWF") {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

function containsSWFObjects() {

    //Try to get all OBJECT tags
    var objects = document.getElementsByTagName('object');  
    var i ,j ;


    for (i=0; i < objects.length; i++) {
        //Check for <object width="400" height="400" data="helloworld.swf"></object> 
        var data = objects[i].getAttribute("data");
        if (data) {
            if (isSwfFile(data)) {
                console.log(data);
                return true;
            }
        }

        //Check for <param name="movie" value="file.swf"/> 
        //and       <param name="SRC" value="bookmark.swf">
        var param = objects[i].getElementsByTagName('param');

        for (j=0; j < param.lenght; j++) {
            var name = param[j].getAttribute("name").toUpperCase();
            if (name) {
                if ( name == "MOVIE" || name == "SRC") { 
                    if ( isSwfFile( param[j].getAttribute("value") ) ) { 
                        console.log(param[j].getAttribute("value"));
                        return true;
                    }
                }
             }
         }         
    }

    //Check for EMBED tag
    var embed = document.getElementsByTagName('embed');
    for (i=0; i < len; i++) {
        //Check for <embed src="file.swf"> 
        var src = embed[i].getAttribute('src');
        if (src) {
            if (isSwfFile(src)) {
                console.log(src);
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}


if ( containsSWFObjects() ) {
    console.log("Contain SWFs");
} else {
    console.log("Doesn't contain SWFs");
}
```